# JSON to apex deserilisation

Tags: apex

Can Somebody assist me in deserialsing below JSON.I tried a wrapper class which provides an error 'Expected FromJSON.cls_results but found '14.0.0.0''

```
{
    "d": {
        "GetContextWebInformation": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.ContextWebInformation"
            },
            "FormDigestTimeoutSeconds": 1800,
            "FormDigestValue": "0x285C94C29511393CC2F7B0856ED2301AF583B245C1AB8FA0E44A163B26048B9F9A9AF5C87413B5B86D2106080F8CD1C8D7B39E0CC5D6CAEA3D832EC5C728EBEF,23 Aug 2019 05:16:57 -0000",
            "LibraryVersion": "16.0.19214.12028",
            "SiteFullUrl": "https://o365coe.sharepoint.com/sites/dms",
            "SupportedSchemaVersions": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
                },
                "results": [
                    "14.0.0.0",
                    "15.0.0.0"
                ]
            },
            "WebFullUrl": "https://o365coe.sharepoint.com/sites/dms"
        }
    }
}
```

apex class used:

```
global class fromJSON{
    public cls_d d;
    class cls_d {
        public cls_GetContextWebInformation GetContextWebInformation;
    }
    class cls_GetContextWebInformation {
        public cls_metadata metadata2;
        public Integer FormDigestTimeoutSeconds;    //1800
        public String FormDigestValue;  //0xCC57C215BF3F6BC877697A3FB0FECA71BB10E08D25B5C8428988EBE7C73078F78DDCD30D98B4D81ED8E782AE59CD342E5DDB72A1398BD923D356C3827F37B95D,22 Aug 2019 09:11:35 -0000
            public String LibraryVersion;   //16.0.19214.12024
        public String SiteFullUrl;  //https://o365coe.sharepoint.com/sites/dms
        public cls_SupportedSchemaVersions SupportedSchemaVersions;
        public String WebFullUrl;   //https://o365coe.sharepoint.com/sites/dms
    }
    class cls_metadata {
        public String type; //Collection(Edm.String)
    }
    class cls_SupportedSchemaVersions {
        public cls_metadata metadata1;
        public cls_results[] results;
    }
    class cls_results {
        public String value;
    }
    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you think the error means? What does `'Expected FromJSON.cls_results but found '14.0.0.0''` mean?  Have you looked at what the result type is in the JSON and comparing it to the variable you're trying to set it to?

Comment: You simply need to change `public cls_results[] results` to `public List<String> results`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `results` in JSON is just an array of strings - so you dont need another class for deserialization. You can fix it by following change in you class `fromJSON`:

```
class cls_SupportedSchemaVersions {
    public cls_metadata metadata1;
    public String[] results;
}
```

and you can remove class `cls_results`

---

**NOTE:**

Your class deserialization would have worked **if** `results` was an array of objects with `value` property:

```
"results": [
  {
    "value": "14.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "value": "15.0.0.0"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the point from @salesforce-sas, Apex identifiers have very specific requirements. They have to start with an letter, so you will have a lot of problems with the "__metadata" (your current implementation will simply ignore this property since you are not using strict deserialization):

> Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'

Because of this, and if you need to access this property's value, I recommend you don't try to directly parse your JSON typed deserialization and instead use [JSON.deserializeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) then transfer the data (if desired) from the recursive Map<String, Object> form to your [POTATO](https://twitter.com/ca_peterson/status/1100481781537468417?s=20) structure.

Comment: good point. Or may be just remove `__` or replace it with something more meaningful in JSON string?